# How to use parameters in Visual Studio 2022 with an Access Database

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have created a database in Access 2019

I have created a basic form to display the data from the above table

I would like to filter the data to show only certain countries – like below

The where clause is hard code and so my question is how can I dynamically change the filter clause say from ‘Aus’ to ‘UK’.
a)  I have tried using a parameter ‘CountryName’ as see in the Fill, GetData (CountryName), but I am unable to use the parameter in the Query Builder.  How can this be done if possible?

b)  Is there a way to change the Fill Query Property (CommandText) by code as I am unable to see the correct properties to use – see below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are creating a typed `DataSet`. In that case, just leave the default query as it is for each table adapter. You can then call `Fill` or `GetData` on a table adapter to get all the data in the corresponding table. If you want to be able to filter the data, add a new query with method names that reflect the filter, e.g. if you want to filter by the `CountryName` column then name the methods `FillByCountryName` and `GetDataByCountryName`. In the Query Builder, you have to use `?` as parameter placeholders rather than names like `@CountryName`, e.g.

```sql
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE CountryName = ?
```

In code, you would then do something like this:

```vb
Dim countryName = "UK"

myTableAdapter.FillByCountryName(myDataSet.MyTable, countryName)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
DECLARE @CountryName AS NVARCHAR(50) = 'uk'

SELECT CountryName FROM MyTable

WHERE CountryName = @CountryName
```

How this would translate to code:

```
Public Sub GetCountry()
    DefaultCatalog = "MyTable"
    Dim selectStatement = "SELECT CountyrName  FROM MyTable WHERE CountyrName = @CountryName"
    Using cn As New SqlConnection With {.ConnectionString = ConnectionString}
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand With {.Connection = cn, .CommandText = selectStatement}
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CountryName", "uk")
            cn.Open()
            Dim reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            If reader.HasRows Then
                reader.Read()
                Console.WriteLine(reader.GetString(0))
            End If
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```